# Is it reasonable to create a presentation in R markdown (no internet connection on the presenter PC)

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, presentation, slidy

I'm going to prepare a presentation that will contain a graphs and tables that are output of the R! and Python scripts.

Thus, although R-Markdown in many cases do not provide so visually appealing output as [Prezi](https://prezi.com), it has other advantages such as being an Open Source and allowing me to export the results (to HTML) without paying.
I would like to prepare my presentation in R-Markdown with `slidy` or [slidyfy](http://slidify.org/).

However my concern is that on the presentation laptop I will **not** have a R!, RStudio and a web-browser will be probably not the latest one. Laptop will probably not have access to the Internet.

Is it 'safe' to prepare a presentation in .Rmd in such case?
Will I have any problem with generated HTML? Will it be possible to export (properly) any .Rmd to PDF as well

Comment: yes, pandoc has the `--self-contained` option for html export. or indeed, you can generate a PDF with it as well (using LaTeX under the hood)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer but a more a thing to think, You could bring with you a USB key with a portable browser of your need (on which you try).

I don't know much about .Rmd but with a short search, it seems you can embeded html dependencies with your presentation and be autonomous without internet :

> html_dependency_jquery()
>
> html_dependency_bootstrap(theme)
>
> html_dependency_jqueryui()
>
> html_dependency_tocify()
>
> html_dependency_font_awesome()
>
> html_dependency_ionicons()